# Markov Matrix with nth Power

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

I found an MIT video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnssRe5DewE&t=95s) (video between 5:18 - 9:52). **The problem is to find what would $P_n$ be if we know A and $P_0$.**

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
0.6 & 0.2 \\
0.4 & 0.8  \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$p_0 =\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0  \\
\end{bmatrix} $

1) The instructor in the video solved like this:

> $P_n = A^n \cdot P_0 = PD^nP^{-1} \cdot P_0$

2) I would do it like this:

> $p_n = A^n \cdot p_0 = \lambda^n \cdot p_k$
>
> $p_k$ here is the corresponding eigen vector to the eigenvalue. I would take $\lambda = 1$.
>
> So $p_n = 1^k \cdot <1, 2> = <1, 2>$

But the solution he gave was $(1/3)   \cdot <1,2>$. So apparently our answers are different.

So which method is correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following what you're trying to do. Are you trying to find an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$ and nonnegative entries (i.e. a nonzero invariant measure)? If so, both $(1,2)^T$ and $(1/3,2/3)^T$ are such, but $(1/3,2/3)^T$ is normalized, which means it additionally represents an invariant *distribution*, which is desirable for the probability setting. If you are trying to look at $P_n$ for finite $n$, there is no reason to expect this is an eigenvector at all!

Comment: The first one: you need a change of base to diagonalize the matrix, so that $A=PDP^{-1}$. Now it is easy to see how  $A^n=PD^nP^{-1}$.

Comment: @N74 I know the $A^n = PD^nP^{-1}$ equation, but I thought I can do it like $P_n = \lambda \cdot P_k$ as well, but my answer is not correct comparing of doing $A^n = PD^nP^{-1}$

Comment: @munmunbb Why should $P_n$ be an eigenvector itself? (This is again for finite $n$, not $n \to \infty$: as $n \to \infty$ you *do* get $P_n$ going to the eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$.)

Comment: $AP_n=\lambda P_n$ only if $P_n$ is an eigenvector. But this is not always the case.

Comment: @Ian FYI I edited the question.

Comment: @N74 But I calculated that <2,1> is the eigenvector when $\lambda = 1$ tho...

Comment: @munmunbb Are you wondering why $\lim_{n \to \infty} P_n$ is $(1/3) (1,2)^T$ instead of just $(1,2)^T$? First of all that will always happen: $P_\infty$ will be a probability vector if $P_0$ was. But you could see it from the linear algebra perspective by calculating $P^{-1} P_0$; you will find its first component is $1/3$, and this factor of $1/3$ persists. Note also that these are both eigenvectors with eigenvalue $1$; we say things like "the eigenvector" but this is really misleading, as each eigenvalue has infinitely many eigenvectors.

Comment: @Ian I see... is that why we need to normalize the eigenvector so each eigenvalue will have only one eigenvector?

Comment: @munmunbb Could you give us $P_0$ and $A$ so we don't have to watch the video? It is good practice to make the questions self-contained. Also use the correct notation to ease reading: $p_0$, $p_n$, ... are **lowercase** because they are vectors.

Comment: @munmunbb You don't have to normalize the eigenvector itself, but if you don't, then the normalization will fall out of $P^{-1}$ anyway. Also, if you do normalize the eigenvector, then you don't even need to calculate $P^{-1}$ in order to know the limit: it will just be the normalized eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$ (provided the eigenspace with eigenvalue $1$ is one-dimensional, which is usually but not always the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s untangle your notation a bit and call the eigenvector that you’re using $v$. If your approach were correct, then it should hold for all $n$. In particular, $p_0=A^0v=\lambda^0v=v$, so this clearly can’t work for an arbitrary initial distribution $p_0$.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is incorrect because you restrict to a particular value for $p_0$. It is true that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then you have:
$$A^n v=\lambda^n v$$
But you have to compute $A^n p_0$ instead, and you cannot choose $p_0$ because it is part of the problem statement. In other words, you cannot assume $p_0=v$, so the first line of your solution is false.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I thought my answer is wrong because I didn't normalize the eigenvector, but if I normalize it, it will be correct...

Comment: @munmunbb The first equation after "I would do it like this:" is false.